# Do I need a visa to transit through Manchester?

Tags: visas

My boyfriend and I are travelling from Reykjavik to Spain with a layover of a few hours in Manchester.
He is Cuban, so has Cuban passport, and he also have the visa Schengen, visa for USA and permanent residence in Iceland. My question is, does he need a extra visa for the UK? I'm not sure if we need to go through passport control because for us is not a need but sometimes when you arrive to the airport there is no other choice. What I do know is that we don't need to change terminal (terminal 1).
For what I read, if he doesn't go through passport control, he doesn't need anything, but if they make us go through that and then again inside, is there anyway he can pass without extra visa? Maybe proving he is leaving that same day, or with any of the other visas?

Comment: Try this https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: As a permanent resident of Iceland your boyfriend does not need a Schengen Visa. But make sure his papers are in order, as you are leaving, and re entering the Schengen area.

Comment: Which airline(s)? Did you book the two legs as connecting flights on a single ticket (one PNR) or as self-transfer? Will you have checked baggage? If you have separate tickets and checked luggage you’ll likely need to clear immigration

Comment: When you check the visa checker, read the exceptions. For transit that involves passing through passport control, it's going to say he needs a visa "unless...." One of the conditions under "unless" is having a common-format residence permit from an EEA country, so he ought to be fine without a UK visa (assuming his permit is in the common format, which it probably is).